# Add multiple people to one form dynamically. Python and Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I want to make a form for a case entry.  This form should be able to take one or more people associated with it dynamically.  Basically, start with one person, and if another person is needed to click a button to say "add a person".  This should populate all the fields for a person to be associated with the same case entry without submitting until every person that needs to be entered is entered.

I know how to do this with just one person but am at a complete loss for adding multiple people dynamically to the same form.  So I have no code to show because I have no idea how to implement this or start.

Comment: Multiple forms together for objects that have something in common are *formsets*, you can read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/) about formsets first.

Comment: That is what I needed.  Thank you SUTerliakov.